# Whether virtual function coverage violates LSP?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle

I am learning design patterns, but I think C++ virtual function rewriting violates LSP.

1. Subclasses can implement the abstract methods of the parent class, but they cannot override the non-abstract methods of the parent class.
2. Subclasses can add their own unique methods.
3. When a subclass overrides or implements a parent class's methods, the method's preconditions (that is, the method's formal parameters) are more lenient than the parent class's input parameters.
4. When a subclass's method implements the abstract method of the parent class, the postcondition of the method (that is, the return value of the method) is stricter than the parent class.

But in order to achieve polymorphism, I have to rewrite(override).
Is it that I understand it wrong?

```
class Animal;
class Cat;

void fun(Animal *xyz) { xyz->eat(); }

class Animal
{
 public:
    virtual void eat() { ::std::cout << "I'm eating generic food."; }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
  public:
    // override.
    // Whether it violates the principle？
    void eat() { ::std::cout << "I'm eating a rat."; }
};
```

Comment: LSP only says you can substitute a base object by a derived object. It doesn't say the derived objet has to override everything the base object provides.

Comment: If you don't know about polymorphism I could see how it would be surprising but once you learn about it I don't see what would be surprising about virtual dispatch.

Comment: I have never heard that requirement as part of Liskov's principle, probably because it says no such thing. Where did you find it?

Comment: I added the content

Comment: Classic OOP is (hopefully) virtually dead. Implementation inheritance was found to be too fragile and was soon (20 years ago?) retired in favor of interface inheritance (structs with only pure virtual functions). But then, innovation kept on coming and nowadays in modern languages, type classes or variations thereof (e.g. traits in Rust) are the state of the art. So, if you need to "learn" OOP for a test, do it - but don't take it too seriously. It always was more of an ad hoc thing than a science.

Answer (score 1):

LSP requires that a subclass must uphold its superclass' contract.

That implies the 4 rules you mention about parameters and return types, but the contract can *also* include a lot of stuff that isn't captured in code (although it would be nice if it was captured in comments!).

There is no other requirement, so unless there is a rule in `Animal`'s contract that says it must eat only generic food, then your override is fine.  If there *is* such a rule, then you shouldn't make the `eat` method virtual.